# Next.js viewport meta tags should not be used in _document.js's <Head>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to use the viewport meta tag to disable the page zoom in the `_document.js` file in the Next.js.

```js
<Html>
   <Head>
      <link rel="icon" href="/static/images/logo/favicon.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0" />
   </Head>
</Html>
```

But it's not working and says viewport meta tags should not be used in `_document.js`'s `<Head>`.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Meta tags added to the custom `_document` cannot be deduped. This means the proper way to overwrite the `viewport` meta tag is to do it in your pages.

From [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-viewport-meta):

> Adding `<meta name="viewport" ...>` in `pages/_document.js` will lead to unexpected results since it cannot be deduped. The viewport tag should be handled by `next/head` in `pages/_app.js`.

Since you probably want to apply it to all pages I'd recommend you do it in `_app`.

```js
// pages/_app

import Head from 'next/head'

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0" />
            </Head>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
    )
}

export default App
```

Make sure to use `'next/head'` and not `'next/document'` here.

Comment: My IDE can't find `Head` in `next/head`!

Answer (score 6):

The viewport tag should be handled by `next/head` in `pages/_app.js`. So you can either move it to the `_app.js` file or if it doesn't exist yet, you can create one like this:

```js
import Head from 'next/head'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/static/images/logo/favicon.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```